# Correct type of StaticRouter context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Server side rendering, got this typescript error:

```
<StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
  <App />
</StaticRouter>
```

> *Type '{ children: Element; context: RouterContext; location: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> StaticRouterProps'. Property 'context' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & StaticRouterProps'.ts(2322)*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's now StaticRouterProvider not StaticRouter for those still looking. A lot of tutorials and repo's still have StaticRouter.

Answer (score 0):

`StaticRouterContext` if you install [@types/react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router)